# python triangle angles returns null

Tags: python

A function that returns the value of triangle angles in degrees from length of the sides, the results are integers sorted from lowest to highest

```
from math import acos, degrees

def angles(a, b, c):
    alpha = beta = gamma = 0
    if a !=0 and b != 0 and c != 0:
        if a + b < c or a + c < b or b + c < a:
            return [alpha, beta, gamma]
        else:
            alpha = int(degrees(acos(( c*c + b*b - a*a ) / (2 * c * b))))
            beta = int(degrees(acos(( a*a + c*c - b*b ) / (2 * a * c))))
            gamma = int(degrees(acos(( a*a + b*b - c*c ) / (2 * a * b))))
            return list.sort([alpha, beta, gamma])
```

why do I get `None` as a result?

Comment: When do you get `null` (?) as result? Please provide a sample input case where you receive `null`...

Comment: [4, 4, 4] fe. but it's the case for every list

Comment: `sort`, sorts in place, it does not return anything. `angles = [a, b, g]; angles.sort(); return angles`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.sort` sorts the list in-place and returns `None`. You could use `sorted` instead:

```
return sorted([alpha, beta, gamma])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

from math import acos, degrees

```
def angles(a, b, c):
    alpha = beta = gamma = 0
    if a !=0 and b != 0 and c != 0:
        if a + b < c or a + c < b or b + c < a:
            return [alpha, beta, gamma]
        else:
            alpha = int(degrees(acos(( c*c + b*b - a*a ) / (2 * c * b))))
            beta = int(degrees(acos(( a*a + c*c - b*b ) / (2 * a * c))))
            gamma = int(degrees(acos(( a*a + b*b - c*c ) / (2 * a * b))))
            lst = [alpha, beta, gamma]
            lst.sort()
            return lst

print angles(4,4,4)
```